# Highcharts - Change zone color according to a custom point

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors

I have data like this:

```
data: [
     {x:Date.UTC(2022,9,25,00,10),y:23,ps:"HCE"},
     {x:Date.UTC(2022,9,25,00,20),y:24,ps:"HPE"},
     {x:Date.UTC(2022,9,25,00,30),y:23,ps:"HCH"},
     {x:Date.UTC(2022,9,25,00,40),y:24,ps:"HCH"}
]
```

With this, I get a single color line graph.
What I would like to do is to create zones as below:

```
zones: [
    {value: 'HCE', color: 'red'},
    {value: 'HPE', color: 'blue'},
    {value: 'HCH', color: 'green'}
]
```

However, I can't find a way to get the value of the "ps" point to change the color of my curve.
Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `zones.value` option expects a number as a key value, so It can't be done this way. I don't clearly understand the goal of the proposed notation. Could you please clarify or provide an example image of expected zone colors based on this data?

Comment: In fact, I have a curve drawn by my y values. For each point I have an associated "ps" value. I would like if possible to change the color of the curve according to this "ps" value. I can replace the text "HCE",... by 1, 2, and 3 it's not a problem but how to take the "ps" value instead of "y" in zones part?

Comment: This is not possible in such a form, because zones need to associate `zones.value` with the value on an axis (depending on the zone type - xAxis or yAxis). To sum up, `zones.value` always need real reflection on the axis, so it can not be a random number. I've created two examples of workarounds (the first one use a multicolor_series plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tr3f4gqh/) and the second one imitates your requirements using in facts `point.x` values (https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fthwv85r/) . Let me know if any of them are useful for you or need to be improved

Comment: It's perfect, it's exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you !

Comment: That's great! Then, I'm adding this as the main answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in such a form, because zones need to associate `zones.value` with the value on an axis (depending on the zone type - xAxis or yAxis). To sum up, `zones.value` always need real reflection on the axis, so it can not be a random number.

I've created two examples of workarounds:

Using `multicolor_series` plugin:

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tr3f4gqh/

**Reference:**
https://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/

Imitating string values by using `point.x` updated on `load()` event:

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fthwv85r/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zoneAxis